# How to implement interface method with return type is an interface in Golang

Tags: interface, go

Here is my code:

```
type IA interface {
    FB() IB
}

type IB interface {
    Bar() string
}

type A struct {
    b *B
}

func (a *A) FB() *B {
    return a.b
}

type B struct{}

func (b *B) Bar() string {
    return "Bar!"
}
```

I get an error:

```
cannot use a (type *A) as type IA in function argument:
    *A does not implement IA (wrong type for FB method)
        have FB() *B
        want FB() IB
```

Here is the full code: http://play.golang.org/p/udhsZgW3W2
I should edit the **IA** interface or modifi my **A** struct?
What if I define IA, IB in a other package (so I can share these interface), I must import my package and use the IB as returned type of A.FB(), is it right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just change

```
func (a *A) FB() *B {
    return a.b
}
```

into

```
func (a *A) FB() IB {
    return a.b
}
```

Surely `IB` can be defined in another package. So if both interfaces are defined in package `foo` and the implementations are in package `bar`, then the declaration is

```
type IA interface {
    FB() IB
}
```

while the implementation is

```
func (a *A) FB() foo.IB {
    return a.b
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The problem is that we would like to have the interfaces in a new file without being able to change the original definition.

Comment: @epsalon How does your problem relate to the original one? Please describe s bit more.

Comment: I think @epsalon's question is quite pertinent. Assuming both A and B are defined in a package that is separate and inaccessible. How can one define interfaces IA and IB retrospectively? An example of when you might want to do this is if you are trying to define these interfaces in order to use mocks for both A and B in a completely different package without being able to modify the original files where A and B are declared.

Comment: Yes, @ishaaq, that's exactly my issue.

Comment: @ishaaq, I have exactly the same issue in mocking objects. Any solution?