# How to create an interface of a Library Struct that have a method returning a type defined within the Library

Tags: go

I have a Library that I want to interface with loosely. So I need to create interface type rather than calling directly the types from the library.

How can I create an interface of a Library Struct that have a method returning a type defined within the Library ?

Here is an example ([also in playground](https://go.dev/play/p/TMDEQtIRbkY)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type LibraryCompositor struct {
    name string
}

func (l *LibraryCompositor) Compose() LibrarySong {
    return LibrarySong{title: "foo"}
}

type LibrarySong struct {
    title string
}

func (l LibrarySong) Score() string {
    return "Am-G-D-A"
}

type Compositor interface {
    Compose() Song
}

type Song interface {
    Score() string
}

type Orchestra struct {
    compositor Compositor
    musicians  []Musician
}

type Musician struct {
    name string
}

func (o Orchestra) play() {
    return
}

func main() {
    l := LibraryCompositor{name: "bar"}

    var c Compositor
    c = &l
    o := Orchestra{compositor: c}
    fmt.Println(o.compositor.Compose().Score())
}
```

When I run this I have the error:

```
./prog.go:48:6: cannot use &l (value of type *LibraryCompositor) as Compositor value in assignment: *LibraryCompositor does not implement Compositor (wrong type for method Compose)
        have Compose() LibrarySong
        want Compose() Song
```

It works if I use the `LibrarySong` type in my interface definition:

```
type Compositor interface {
    Compose() LibrarySong
}
```

But I don't want this because it creates a strong coupling with the library

Any ideas ?

PS: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921634/how-to-implement-interface-method-with-return-type-is-an-interface-in-golang) is similar but does not answer exactly my use case

Comment: `func (l *LibraryCompositor) Compose() Song`. Interface methods must match literal. You cannot do exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `LibraryCompositor` needs to return the same type from `Compose` as the interface describes which is `Song` and not `LibrarySong`.

Try using:

```
func (l *LibraryCompositor) Compose() Song {
    return LibrarySong{title: "foo"}
}
```

You can still return the struct since it fulfills the `Song` interface requirements, but the actual method declaration should match the `Compositor` interface.

Comment: but this mean I would need to change the library code which is not what I want

Comment: Yes you cannot do what you're trying to do. It simply isn't possible. You're trying to return a struct where an interface is specified. You can't break the rules of the language just because you want to.

Comment: I'm not asking how to break the rules of the language; I'm simply asking for a solution to a quite common pattern in programming: how to abstract my code from a specific library using interface

Comment: That is how you do it. As Volker said, you can't do exactly what you're trying to.